# Call a file path from another Class Function into another Class

Tags: python, class, matplotlib, tkinter

i'm currently trying to create a GUI for 2D plotter machine. The GUI can open the file from File menu, read and plot the gcode.

For now, in my code, I have a 'MenuBar' class where 'Upload File' label will open the 'browseFile' function in the same class. Then the file path will be read by 'getFilePath' function in the same class.
In 'App' class, there is 'update' function that intended to read the filepath and extract the gcode and plot the gcode at the same time.

However, it is not working and the 'AttributeError' occur.
Why is that happened? Is it my method in calling the variable from another class is wrong?
What should I do to correct it?

Attached picture is the working GUI environment if it works:

[image]

This is the code for now:

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu
    from tkinter.filedialog import *
    from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
    from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
    import tkinter.messagebox
    import tkinter as tk
    
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg #, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    
    import time
    import turtle
    import os
    import sys
    import logging
    import ruamel.yaml
            
    
    class MenuBar(tk.Menu, object):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            tk.Menu.__init__(self, parent)
            
            fileMenu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
            self.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=fileMenu)
            fileMenu.add_command(label="Upload File", command=self.browseFile)
            fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=1, command=self.quit)
    
            settingMenu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
            self.add_cascade(label="Settings", underline=0, menu=settingMenu)
            settingMenu.add_command(label="Machine Variable")
            
            aboutMenu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
            self.add_cascade(label="About", underline=0, menu=aboutMenu)
            #aboutMenu.add_command(label="Machine Variable")
            
        def quit(self):
            sys.exit(0)
            
        def browseFile(self):
            tmp = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "./", title = "select gcode file", filetypes = (("gcode files", "*.gcode"), ("gio files", "*.gio"), ("nc files", "*.nc"), ("all files", "*.*")))
            self.filepathEntry = tmp     
    
        def getFilePath(self):
            return self.filepathEntry.get()
        
    
    class App(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            
            tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Plotter Interface")
            menubar = MenuBar(self)
            self.config(menu=menubar)
            
            container = tk.Frame(self)
            container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand = True)
            
            container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            
            top_frame = tk.Frame(container)
            top_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
            
            topLeftFrame = tk.Frame(top_frame, relief='solid', bd=1)
            topLeftFrame.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=NW, padx=0, pady=0) 
            
            topRightFrame = tk.Frame(top_frame, relief='solid', bd=1)
            topRightFrame.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=NE, padx=0, pady=0)
            
            #def update():
                #zero=0
                #one=zero+1
                #print(one)
            
         
            homebutton = tk.Button(topLeftFrame, height=50, width=50, command=None)
            homebutton.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=0)
            
            
            playbutton = tk.Button(topLeftFrame, height=50, width=50, command=None)
            playbutton.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=0, pady=0)
    
    
            pausebutton = tk.Button(topLeftFrame, height=50, width=50, command=None)
            pausebutton.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=0, pady=0)
            
            
            stopbutton = tk.Button(topLeftFrame, height=50, width=50, command=None)
            stopbutton.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=0, pady=0)
            
    
            updownbutton = tk.Button(topLeftFrame, height=50, width=50, command=None)
            updownbutton.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=0, pady=0)
      
    
            nextbutton = tk.Button(topRightFrame, height=50, width=50, command=None)
            nextbutton.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=0, pady=0)
            
            
            prevbutton = tk.Button(topRightFrame, height=50, width=50, command=None)
            prevbutton.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=0)
            
            bottom_frame = tk.Frame(container)
            bottom_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill='both', expand=True)
            
            def update(self):
                gcode = extractGcode(self.MenuBar.getFilePath())
                self.diagramFrame.plot(gcode)
            update(self)
            
            self.diagramFrame = DiagramFrame(bottom_frame)
            self.diagramFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill='both', expand=True)
    
            
    class DiagramFrame(tk.Frame):
    
        def __init__(self, parent):
            super().__init__(parent)
            
            frame_right = tk.Frame(self)
            frame_right.pack(side=RIGHT, fill='both', expand=True)
            
            label1 = tk.Label(frame_right, text="Drawing Plotter view", anchor='w', padx=0, pady=0) #font=("Verdana", 12))
            label1.pack(side=TOP, fill='both')
            
            self.f = Figure(figsize=(8,8), dpi=100)
            self.a = self.f.add_subplot(111)
            self.a.plot(0, 0, 'r')
            self.a.plot(0, 0, 'g')  
            self.a.axis("equal")    
            self.a.grid(color='grey', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5)  
    
            self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, frame_right)
            self.canvas.draw()
            self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=BOTTOM, fill='both', expand=True)
            
            #---------------------------------------------------------------------
            
            frame_left = tk.Frame(self)
            frame_left.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
            
            label2 = tk.Label(frame_left, text="Gcode view", anchor='w', padx=0, pady=0) #font=("Verdana", 9))
            label2.pack(side=TOP, fill='both')
            
            self.fileDisplayText = Text(frame_left, width=27, font=(9))
            self.fileDisplayText.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor='w', fill='y', expand=True)
    
    
        def plot(self, data):
            self.a.clear()
            self.a.plot(data.X, data.Y, 'r')
            self.a.plot(data.U, data.V, 'g')  
            self.a.axis("equal")    
            self.a.grid(color='grey', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5)
            self.a.legend(["XY", "UV"])  
    
            self.canvas.draw()
    
    
    class Data:
        X = []
        Y = []
        U = []
        V = []
    
    #parse a float number with a key
    def parseFloatNumber(string, key) :
        start = string.find(key) + 1
        end = string.find(' ', start)
        if not (start == 0) : #if the number at the key has been found
            return float(string[start:end])
        else :
            return 0
        
    def extractGcode(gcodeFile):
        f = open(gcodeFile, "r")
        
        data = Data()
        
        #extract positions out of gcode
        integralPosition = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
        mode = 'abs'
        for line in f.readlines() :
    
            if (line[0:3] == 'G28') : #home
                integralPosition = [0,0,0,0]
                data.X.append(integralPosition[0])
                data.Y.append(integralPosition[1])
                data.U.append(integralPosition[2])
                data.V.append(integralPosition[3])
                continue
                
            if (line[0:3] == 'G90') : #absolute mode
                mode = 'abs'
                continue
                
            if (line[0:3] == 'G91') : #relative mode
                mode = 'rel'
                continue
                
            if not ((line[0:3] == 'G00') or (line[0:3] == 'G01')) :
                continue
            
            if (mode == 'abs') : 
                data.X.append(parseFloatNumber(line, 'X'))
                data.Y.append(parseFloatNumber(line, 'Y'))
                data.U.append(parseFloatNumber(line, 'U'))
                data.V.append(parseFloatNumber(line, 'V'))
            else :
                integralPosition[0] = integralPosition[0] + parseFloatNumber(line, 'X')
                integralPosition[1] = integralPosition[1] + parseFloatNumber(line, 'Y')
                integralPosition[2] = integralPosition[2] + parseFloatNumber(line, 'U')
                integralPosition[3] = integralPosition[3] + parseFloatNumber(line, 'V')
                data.X.append(integralPosition[0])
                data.Y.append(integralPosition[1])
                data.U.append(integralPosition[2])
                data.V.append(integralPosition[3])
                
        f.close()
        
        return data
    
    app=App()
    app.mainloop()
```

This is the full traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/quantum/Plotter Machine Interface/gcodeDisplay (TEST1.3).py", line 242, in <module>
     app=App()
   File "/home/quantum/Plotter Machine Interface/gcodeDisplay (TEST1.3).py", line 123, in init
     update(self)
   File "/home/quantum/Plotter Machine Interface/gcodeDisplay (TEST1.3).py", line 121, in update
     gcode = extractGcode(self.MenuBar.getFilePath())
   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2354, in getattr
     return getattr(self.tk, attr) AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'MenuBar'
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Hi ewong, I have include also the full traceback error

Answer (score 0):

From what I noticed from the following code:

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Plotter Interface")
        menubar = MenuBar(self)
        self.config(menu=menubar)
        .
        .
        .
       
        def update(self):
            gcode = extractGcode(self.MenuBar.getFilePath())
            self.diagramFrame.plot(gcode)
        update(self)
```

The problem is in the first part, you set `menubar = MenuBar(self)`;
but in the `update` method, you refer to `self.MenuBar.getFilePath()`.

Also, (in hindsight, thus this edit) that's not how
you'd call `update()`.

What I believe you should do is the following:

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Plotter Interface")
        self.menubar = MenuBar(self)
        self.config(menu=self.menubar)
        .
        .
        .
        self.update()
     
        self.diagramFrame = DiagramFrame(bottom_frame)
        self.diagramFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill='both', expand=True)

    def update(self):
        gcode = extractGcode(self.menubar.getFilePath())
        self.diagramFrame.plot(gcode)
```

This is what I feel the issue is; but I might have missed something about tkapp.

Comment: Hi ewong, thank you very much but i still get the error.

Comment: The same error or a different error?

Comment: same error. It's ok, i will try different way for calling the file path

Comment: I've updated the code and changed how you should call ```update()```.